# What is the meaning of sol$convergence = 1 or 2 with solnp()?

Tags: r, output, nonlinear-optimization, convergence

I am using solnp() in R. I know the convergence output of 0 indicates successful convergence. But what is the difference between values of 1 or 2? I can't seem to find the answer in the R documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Digging in the source code of `solnp()` I found the following

```
if (get(".solnp_errors", envir = .solnpenv) == 1) {
    convergence = 2
    if (trace) 
        cat(paste("\nsolnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.\n", 
            sep = ""))
}
else {
    if (.vnorm(c(tt[1], tt[2])) <= tol) {
        convergence = 0
        if (trace) 
            cat(paste("\nsolnp--> Completed in ", .solnp_iter, 
              " iterations\n", sep = ""))
    }
    else {
        convergence = 1
        if (trace) 
            cat(paste("\nsolnp--> Exiting after maximum number of iterations\n", 
              "Tolerance not achieved\n", sep = ""))
    }
}
```

This means that

- congergence = 0: Success
- convergence = 1: Maximum amount of iterations reached
- convergence = 2: Solution not reliable due to problems inverting the Hessian

Comment: Ah fantastic! Thanks! So I guess in the case of 2, that means perhaps my starting values need re-jigging I guess.